# R for loop that passes only once though a vector

Tags: r

I would like to concatenate an equation for a logistic model first followed by a linear model.

For model 1, o1=p1+p2+p3 (binomial will be input to family parameter in glm function)

For model 2, o2=p1+p2+p3 (gaussian will be input to family parameter in glm function)

In the real life example, there will be many more models.

Here is the basic scenario:

```
outcome <- c("o1", "o2")
predictor <- c("p1", "p2", "p3")
link=c("binomial", "gaussian")


try <- function(outcomes, predictors) {
for(o in outcome) {
  eq <- paste(o, "~")
  for(p in predictor) {
    eq=paste0(eq, p, "+")
  }
  # remove extra +
eq <- substr(eq,1,nchar(eq)-1)

# model will go here
eq <- lapply(link, function(x) paste0(x, " - ", eq))
print(eq)
}
}

try(outcomes=outcome, predictors=predictor)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "binomial - o1 ~p1+p2+p3"

[[2]]
[1] "gaussian - o1 ~p1+p2+p3"

[[1]]
[1] "binomial - o2 ~p1+p2+p3"

[[2]]
[1] "gaussian - o2 ~p1+p2+p3"
```

Instead, I want:

```
[1] "binomial - o1 ~p1+p2+p3"

[1] "gaussian - o2 ~p1+p2+p3"
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? I hope you don't intend to parse the character strings. Anyway, you don't need lapply, paste0 is vectorized.

Comment: The issue with your loop is that there are 2 loops! Use one loop with something like `for(i in 1:length(outcome))` and use `outcome[i]` and `link[i]` inside the loop. (Or one of the excellent answers below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
try1 <- function(outcomes, predictors) {
      Map(function(x, y) paste(y, '-', 
            deparse(reformulate(predictors, x))), outcomes, link)   

 }
```

-testing

```
try1(outcomes=outcome, predictors=predictor)
#$o1
#[1] "binomial - o1 ~ p1 + p2 + p3"

#$o2
#[1] "gaussian - o2 ~ p1 + p2 + p3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `try` can be written like below

```
try <- function(outcomes, predictors) {
  as.list(
    paste0(
      do.call(
        paste,
        c(data.frame(link, outcomes), sep = " - ")
      ),
      paste0(" ~ ", paste0(predictors, collapse = " + "))
    )
  )
}
```

such that

```
> try(outcome, predictor)
[[1]]
[1] "binomial - o1 ~ p1 + p2 + p3"

[[2]]
[1] "gaussian - o2 ~ p1 + p2 + p3"
```